# Using crontab in linux to display a message everytime you open terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to display message in terminal:

"Welcome!"

when someone opens the terminal

Comment: `crontab` does not do this. Just add `echo "Welcome!"` to the user's `.bashrc`

Comment: you could also use the files /etc/motd or /etc/issue, see their man pages.

Comment: actually I want to print good morning/good evening/good night according to the time that's why I asked for a solution using crontab .If there is any other method please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print a message when opening a terminal (or logging in via ssh) you should use the message of the day (/etc/motd).

You could use cron to overwrite this file at specific times, and so users will see the current message when they log in:

```
00 1 * * * "/bin/echo 'Good morning' > /etc/motd"
00 12 * * * "/bin/echo 'Good afternoon' > /etc/motd"
00 17 * * * "/bin/echo 'Good evening' > /etc/motd"
```